# CSS - text-overflow: ellipsis fixing

Tags: html, css

i am using text-overflow: ellipsis to make max number of lines in my container article. It works fine but limit start after 1 line and i need to set it on more. (like 3-4) problem is how ever i try it it move everything in my article container away or made no change.

I am new in CSS so i am prolly doing something wrong, can u help me with that?

DEMOs:
[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/gHTjG/)  [LIVE WEBSITE](http://funedit.com/andurit/new)

Part of CSS with ellipsis (full CSS / HTML can be found on demos above):

```
#article-container p {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 168px;
}

#article-container p.more {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: normal;
    width: auto;
}
```

So guys is here anyone who can help me to set it to limit more lines not just one?

Thanks for reading this post

Comment: http://cssmojo.com/line-clamp_for_non_webkit-based_browsers/

Comment: Is there a chance you can gimme working fiddle because i try this and it just remove my p.more :(

Comment: Nope. You can see how it works in the examples on the page. _Understanding_ it and then transferring it into your environment is your job …

Answer (score 1):

Elipse in CSS currently only does 1 line. There're a few javascript libraries that will help you accomplish what you want. http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/ for example.

Comment: I need to fix it without JS , just HTML + CSS

Comment: Perhaps you could try using `max-height` and `max-width` and setting `overflow:hidden`. But this will probably show half a letter on some browsers depending on the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do more than 1 line with CSS (at least not in a way that is compatible with most browsers), but you can trim it using PHP if you don't want to use Javascript.

```
<?php
function Truncate($string, $length=50, $stopanywhere=false) {
    if (strlen($string) > $length) {
        //limit hit!
        $string = substr($string,0,($length -3));
        if ($stopanywhere) {
            //cut off anywhere
            $string .= '...';
        } else{
            //cut off after word
            $string = substr($string,0,strrpos($string,' ')).'...';
        }
    }
    return $string;
}
?>
```

Define $string with your text, the text that you want limited.

Comment: Yea mate i have no problem to limit it by PHP, the problem is thats a code for my friend and he want to limit it by CSS / HTML ,isnt there way to limit it by width / height or something?

Comment: Currently there is no way to do this with pure CSS and add ellipsis, in a way that is compatible across all modern day browsers. At least not without using CSS "hacks" that is. Try the link that someone posted in a comment to your question. Can't guarantee that it will produce a reliable result though.